# A r.v. $Y\sim U]0;1[$ and $\mu$ a proba measure on $B( \mathbb{R})$. Build a new r.v. $X$ of law $\mu$ by composing $Y$ with a well chose fct

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

#### Question:

Given a r.v. $Y \sim U]0;1[$ and $ \mu $ a probability measure on $B( \mathbb{R})$. Build a new r.v. $X$ of law $ \mu $ by composing $Y$ with a well chose function.

#### Answer:

1- We define $0<t = F_X(x)=P(X<x)= \mu (] -\infty; x]) < 1 $

2- Our objective is to get $ F_X(F^{-1}_X(t)) = t $. If we define $F^{-1}_X(t) = inf \left \{  x \in \mathbb{R} : F_X(x)  \geq t \right \}$ we indeed get that $ F_X(F^{-1}_X(t)) = t $.
More over if $t \leq F_X(x) \Rightarrow F^{-1}_X(t) \leq x$

3- From "2-" and by construction we have that $P(F^{-1}_X(Y) \leq X) = P(Y \leq F_X(X)) = F_X(X)$

My weak point here is that I do not succeed to rigoursly justify that $t \leq F_X(x) \Rightarrow F^{-1}_X(t) \leq x$ means that $\left \{ F^{-1}_X(Y) \leq X \right \} = \left \{ Y \leq F_X(X) \right \}$
How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: I think you meant $\inf\{x\in\Bbb R:F_X(x)>t\}$ (not $<$). See Wikipedia's [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) or Embrechts−Hofert [“A note on generalized inverses”](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf).

Comment: @nejimban thnk for your time and comment. i have't yet red your link but i have writen an answer, can you please tell me if it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @nejimban you are right i have edited this typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

Below some attempt but I am not sure about it.

-Option I

*Prove: $\left \{ Y≤F_X(x) \right \} ⊆ \left \{ F_X^{−1}(Y)≤x \right \}$*
1.$ Y \sim ]0;1[ $ and $0< F_X(x) < 1$ so if $Y≤F_X(x) \Rightarrow \exists x' $ s.t. $Y=F_X(X')$. And so we have that $\left \{Y≤F_X(x) \right \} = \left \{ F_X(X')≤F_X(x) \right \}$. Moreover $ X' \leq X$ as $F_X(x)$ is a no decreasing function.
2.Now by the definition of $F^{-1}_X$ we have that $F^{-1}_X(Y) = F^{-1}_X( F_X(X') ) = X'$, and since $x <x'$
3.In conclusion $\left \{Y≤F_X(x) \right \} = \left \{ F_X(X')≤F_X(x) \right \} ⊆ \left \{ X' ≤ X \right \} = \left \{ F_X^{−1}(Y)≤x \right \} $

*Prove: $\left \{ F_X^{−1}(Y)≤x \right \} ⊆ \left \{ Y≤F_X(x) \right \}$*
1.If $ F_X^{−1}(Y)≤x $ by definition of $F_X^{−1}$ we have that $F_X^{−1}(Y)$ is equal to the smallest possible $x'$ s.t. $F_X(x')$ is at least $Y$. We write $ X' =F_X^{−1}(Y)  \Rightarrow \left \{ F_X^{−1}(Y)≤x \right \} = \left \{ X'≤x \right \}$.
2.If $ \left \{ X'≤x \right \} $ using the fact that $F_X(.)$ is a not decreasing function we have that $F_X(X') \leq F_X(X)$ but $F_X(X') =F_X(F_X^{−1}(Y))=Y$ as we have all ready justify.

-Option II

We take the following inequation $F_X^{-1}(Y) \leq X $ then we apply $F_X(.)$ on both side as it is an increasing function the signe of the inequation is preserved and we get $Y = F_X(F_X^{-1}(Y)) \leq F_X(X)$  that is equivalent to $F_X^{-1}(Y) \leq X $
So we get $\left \{ Y≤F_X(x) \right \} = \left \{ F_X^{−1}(Y)≤x \right \}$

Comment: Up anyone to check my answer?